# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "Hacer la pirula"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

Aunque el diccionario de la RAE no lo recoge entre las acepciones de *[pirula](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TBoTRsg)*, la expresión coloquial `hacer la pirula` se usa en España con el sentido de hacer una pequeña trampa o algo indebido, normalmente relativo a las señales de tráfico.

> Bueno, es prohibido, pero no viene nadie y no hay policía. Voy a **hacer la pirula** y dar la vuelta aquí, que si no nos tenemos que ir hasta el quinto pino para poder dar media vuelta.

Se puede usar en otros contextos no relacionados con las normas de tráfico, pero ese es el principal.

> Ese dependiente me ha debido de **hacer la pirula** al darme el cambio, porque no me salen las cuentas.

¿Cómo ha llegado a formarse ese modismo o expresión de "hacer la pirula" con el significado de "hacer una pequeña trampa"?

Comment: "Bueno, es prohibido" me suena fatal, no debería ser "Bueno, está prohibido"? no sé si realmente es incorrecto o si solo me suena mal...

Comment: @BrianH. tienes razón (podría ser de hecho una pregunta interesante para el sitio). Es "Bueno, **es**tá prohibido [dar la vuelta aquí]", pero cuando escribí ese ejemplo estaba pensando en uno diferente: "Bueno, **es** [dirección] prohibida" y se me cruzaron los cables (y los ejemplos). Creo que ese "Es dirección prohibida" es el único caso en que se usa "Es" y no "Estar". Gracias por el apunte!

Answer (score 3):

Creo que debe ser por su relación con **pirueta**. Ambas palabras, *pirula* y *pirueta* vendrían de *perinola* ("peonza", "trompo"), raíz de la que según Corominas también derivan el aragonés *pirulo*, el italiano *pirlo* y el francés *pirouette*, todas con el mismo significado: "giro", "voltereta", "acrobacia".

Curiosamente en francés una *pirouette* también es una *evasiva*, o sea una forma de desentenderse de alguna responsabilidad, lo cual en esencia también es hacer trampa. Me imagino (y esto obviamente es una suposición mía) que el problema moral de las infracciones se puede suavizar mediante la metáfora de la acrobacia. O sea, *hacer la pirula en el semáforo* es como darte una vuelta en el aire y... ¡ta-rán!

Bueno, ésas serían las especulaciones medio forzadas de un amigo latinoamericano que nunca había escuchado eso de *hacer la pirula*. Y, fuera de tema, para que sepan, en Chile *pirula* es la forma más "soft" de referirse al pene.